# Swiftで電卓アプリ開発

Tags: ios, swift

現在、電卓のアプリを開発しています。が、エラーが発生して進めなくなってしまったため、質問させていただきます。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
イメージ説明実装したい内容は、このボタンをタップしたときに、どのボタンがタップされたのかを表示するということです。

エラーは以下のような内容です。

> [Calculator.ViewController buttonTapped:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7988fea0

buttonTappedメソッドが認識できないと言われてしまっています。 
誤字脱字は確認したので、そちらは問題ないように思われます。認識できないのか、わかりません、、、。

ソースコード以下になります。 
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  Calculator
//

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    //計算結果を表示するラベルを宣言
    var resultLabel = UILabel()
    let xButtonCount = 4 //一行に配置するボタンの数
    let yButtonCount = 4
    //画面の横幅サイズを格納するメンバ変数
    let screenWidth:Double = Double(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width)
    //画面の縦
    let screenHeight:Double = Double(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height)
    //ボタン間の余白
    let buttonMargin = 10.0
    //計算結果表示
    var resultArea = 0.0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //画面全体の縦幅に応じて計算結果表示エリアの縦幅を決定
        switch screenHeight{
            case 480:
                resultArea = 200.0
            case 568:
                resultArea = 250.0
            case 667:
                resultArea = 300.0
            case 736: 
                resultArea = 350.0
            default:
                resultArea = 0.0
        }
        //計算結果のラベル
        resultLabel.frame = CGRect(x:10, y:30, width:screenWidth-20, height:resultArea-30)

        let buttonLabels = [
            "7","8","9","×",
            "4","5","6","-",
            "1","2","3","+",
            "0","C","÷","="
        ]

        for var y=0; y<yButtonCount; y++ {
            for var x=0; x<xButtonCount; x++ {
                //計算機のボタン作成
                var button = UIButton()
                //ボタンの横幅
                var buttonWidth = (screenWidth - (buttonMargin * (Double(xButtonCount)+1)))/Double(xButtonCount)
                //ボタンの縦幅
                var buttonHeight = (screenHeight - resultArea - ((buttonMargin*Double(yButtonCount)+1)))/Double(yButtonCount)
                //ボタンのx座標
                var buttonPositionX = (screenWidth - buttonMargin) / Double(xButtonCount) * Double(x) + buttonMargin
                //ボタンのy座標
                var buttonPositionY = (screenHeight - resultArea - buttonMargin) / Double(yButtonCount) * Double(y) + buttonMargin + resultArea
                //ボタンの配置、サイズ
                button.frame = CGRect(x:buttonPositionX, y:buttonPositionY, width:buttonWidth, height:buttonHeight)
                //背景
                button.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
                //ボタンのラベルタイトル
                var buttonNumber = y * xButtonCount + x
                //ボタンのラベルタイトルを取り出すインデックス番号
                button.setTitle(buttonLabels[buttonNumber],forState: UIControlState.Normal)
                //ボタンタップ時のアクション
                button.addTarget(self, action: "buttonTapped:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
                //ボタン配置
                self.view.addSubview(button)
            }
       }

        //計算結果ラベル設定する
        resultLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()
        resultLabel.font = UIFont(name:"Arial", size: 50)
        resultLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Right
        resultLabel.numberOfLines = 4
        resultLabel.text = "0"

        //計算結果ラベルをviewcontrollerクラスのviewに設置
        self.view.addSubview(resultLabel)

        //ボタンタップメソッド
        func buttonTapped(sender:UIButton){
            var tappedButtonTitle:String = sender.titleLabel!.text!
            println("\(tappedButtonTitle)ボタンがタップされました")
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

Comment: クラス単位で、省略せずにコードを全掲載しないと、どこが間違っているか、指摘はむずかしいかなと思います。

Comment: すみません。コードを修正いたしました。

Answer (score 1):

buttonTapped メソッド内の、

```
var tappedButtonTitle: String = sender.currentTitle!
```

というステートメントを、以下のように変更してみてはいかがでしょう？

```
var tappedButtonTitle: String = sender.titleLabel!.text
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます！変更してみましたが、同じエラーが出てしまいました、、、。

Answer (score 1):

アクションメソッド`buttonTapped(sender: UIButton)`の実装を記述する場所を間違えてますね。

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    //計算結果を表示するラベルを宣言
    var resultLabel = UILabel()
    let xButtonCount = 4 //一行に配置するボタンの数
    let yButtonCount = 4
    //画面の横幅サイズを格納するメンバ変数
    let screenWidth:Double = Double(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width)
    //画面の縦
    let screenHeight:Double = Double(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height)
    //ボタン間の余白
    let buttonMargin = 10.0
    //計算結果表示
    var resultArea = 0.0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //画面全体の縦幅に応じて計算結果表示エリアの縦幅を決定
        switch screenHeight{
            case 480:
                resultArea = 200.0
            case 568:
                resultArea = 250.0
            case 667:
                resultArea = 300.0
            case 736: 
                resultArea = 350.0
            default:
                resultArea = 0.0
        }
        //計算結果のラベル
        resultLabel.frame = CGRect(x:10, y:30, width:screenWidth-20, height:resultArea-30)

        let buttonLabels = [
            "7","8","9","×",
            "4","5","6","-",
            "1","2","3","+",
            "0","C","÷","="
        ]

        for var y=0; y<yButtonCount; y++ {
            for var x=0; x<xButtonCount; x++ {
                //計算機のボタン作成
                var button = UIButton()
                //ボタンの横幅
                var buttonWidth = (screenWidth - (buttonMargin * (Double(xButtonCount)+1)))/Double(xButtonCount)
                //ボタンの縦幅
                var buttonHeight = (screenHeight - resultArea - ((buttonMargin*Double(yButtonCount)+1)))/Double(yButtonCount)
                //ボタンのx座標
                var buttonPositionX = (screenWidth - buttonMargin) / Double(xButtonCount) * Double(x) + buttonMargin
                //ボタンのy座標
                var buttonPositionY = (screenHeight - resultArea - buttonMargin) / Double(yButtonCount) * Double(y) + buttonMargin + resultArea
                //ボタンの配置、サイズ
                button.frame = CGRect(x:buttonPositionX, y:buttonPositionY, width:buttonWidth, height:buttonHeight)
                //背景
                button.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
                //ボタンのラベルタイトル
                var buttonNumber = y * xButtonCount + x
                //ボタンのラベルタイトルを取り出すインデックス番号
                button.setTitle(buttonLabels[buttonNumber],forState: UIControlState.Normal)
                //ボタンタップ時のアクション
                button.addTarget(self, action: "buttonTapped:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
                //ボタン配置
                self.view.addSubview(button)
            }
       }

        //計算結果ラベル設定する
        resultLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()
        resultLabel.font = UIFont(name:"Arial", size: 50)
        resultLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Right
        resultLabel.numberOfLines = 4
        resultLabel.text = "0"

        //計算結果ラベルをviewcontrollerクラスのviewに設置
        self.view.addSubview(resultLabel)

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    //ボタンタップメソッド（viewDidLoad()メソッド内から、ここに移動）
    func buttonTapped(sender:UIButton){
        var tappedButtonTitle:String = sender.titleLabel!.text
        println("\(tappedButtonTitle)ボタンがタップされました")
    }
}
```

Comment: 解決致しました、、、。ありがとうございます。
なぜview did load内にあるとメソッドが認識できなかったのでしょうか？？

Comment: `button.addTarget(self, action: "buttonTapped:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)`の行で、メソッド`buttonTapped()`のレシーバ（Receiver）を`self`すなわち`ViewController`にしているからですね。`ViewController`のメソッドであるべきなのに、`ViewController`のメソッド`viewDidLoad()`のメソッドになっていては、エラーになります。ちょっとゲスなたとえを使うなら、パチンコに行くのに、自分の財布では足りないからといって、子供の財布に手をつけたらダメでしょ、ってことです。自分の子供だからといって、子供のお金は、あなたのお金じゃない。

Comment: 様々な場所で `func hoge(...)` として関数を定義することができますが、中でも型に結び付けられた特殊な関数がメソッドです。構文自体はどちらも同じですが、メソッドは型定義の直下に書く必要があります。メソッドである `viewDidLoad()` の中に書いてしまうと、そのメソッドの外からは見えません。

Comment: @Harawo さんは「メソッドのメソッド」と言われていますが、それぞれのメソッドは型ではありませんから、その中で定義された関数をメソッドと言うには無理があるように思います。

Comment: @unarist コメント欄を使った、会話や論議は避けてくれというのが、主宰者側の方針だそうです。会話や論議は、チャットルームを新設して、そこで行ってくれと、過去注意を受けたことがあります。それに私は従いますので、ここで返信することは避けたいと思います。

Comment: @Harawo 個人的には興味のある話題ですから、Harawoさんがよろしければチャットに移動してお話を伺いたいですが、いかがでしょう？

Comment: @unarist 生産性があるとは思えないので、遠慮いたします。あしからず。